# Remove indent from a specific chapter title in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, tocloft

**Problem:**

I wish that some chapter titles in the TOC are indented but not others.

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newcommand*{\disableboldchapterintoc}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappagefont}{\protect\normalfont}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapfont}{\protect\normalfont}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapleader}{\protect\normalfont\protect\cftdotfill{\protect\cftsecdotsep}}}% 
}

%: ----------------------- Table of contents ------------------------
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% titles in bold
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% page numbers in bold
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}% dot leaders in bold

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\disableboldchapterintoc
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

While test chapter one and test section one can be indented, I wish that the sentences starting with `tempor` and `veniam` should not be indented.

Comment: It is unclear, what purpose the inserted sentence has. Do you want to add a sentence in the table of contents without page number or why does it have not a proper title and a number?

Comment: I've answered your other question about the non-bold appearance of chapter entries in ToC (where you got `\disableboldchapterintoc` from), but longer texts in a ToC look ugly. Please ask yourself if this is really necessary...

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I was an example of an academic project I am working on where the titles are long and must have roman numerals. They are included as appendix.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, thank you for your answer. Since this is a new issue I felt compelled to create a new question rather than build on previous issue. As I stated to Heiko, titles on academic papers tend to be long and it is not something I have influence on at this stage, i.e. they have been published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your existing `\disableboldchapterintoc` macro:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newcommand*{\disableboldandindentchapterintoc}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappagefont}{\protect\normalfont}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapfont}{\protect\normalfont}}
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapleader}{\protect\normalfont\protect\cftdotfill{\protect\cftsecdotsep}}}% 
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\setlength{\protect\cftchapnumwidth}{0pt}}
}

%: ----------------------- Table of contents ------------------------
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% titles in bold
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}% page numbers in bold
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}% dot leaders in bold

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\disableboldandindentchapterintoc
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Then again, if you just want to insert some text in the TOC, you can avoid using a `chapter` in the first place:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One}

\documentclass{book}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. While your solution seems to work in the MWE, I am finding difficulties to get it to work in my academic project. Not sure why, but it does not generate any errors.